# Symfony 3 DateTimeType form field with an optional time component

Tags: symfony

Symfony3's DateTimeType can be set to either required or not, the same flag applies to both the date and time components.

Is there a way to make the time component optional/ e.g. if someone adds data to the date part, the value should be saved correctly, either by using some kind of empty_data attribute or with some custom configuration.

Edit: Using the DateTimeType as a compound choice element

Comment: Use `empty_data` then?

Comment: empty_data adds an attribute to the containing element but does not update the state of the select boxes

Comment: Can't you just attach an event listener to the `PRE_SUBMIT` event and modify incoming data?

Comment: Actually that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. You can mark my answer as a solution then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always modify your data using [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html):

Modify your incoming request to suit your needs:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $evt) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    // modify data
    $event->setData($data);
});
```